# Parse kindle file in Chinese with python

Tags: python

I working on a project for my fiancée and ran across this script she wanted but most of her book are in Chinese. By any means, I don't have much experience in python so guess it's a start for me. I ran into a issue where it can't decode the output I guess and base on my research probably has to do something with encoding needs to be set to utf-8. The question is how do I write this python script to be able to output that.

[Script](https://github.com/robertmartin8/KindleClippings/blob/master/KindleClippings.py)

Error:

`File "KindleClippings.py", line 58, in parse_clippings for highlight in f.read().split("=========="): File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 121: character maps to <undefined>`

Thanks all

Comment: add the code to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 55 in your script from

```
with open(source_file, "r") as f:
```

to

```
with open(source_file, "r", encoding='cp850')
```

If `'cp850'` doesn't work, you can try others like `'cp1252'` or `'utf8'`.

Comment: OP's error message already indicates that it isn't Windows 1252.

Comment: @BioGeek Still error with `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-25: character maps to <undefined>

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: character maps to <undefined>`